# zsh on macOS date modify output of given date (without script)

Tags: macos, date, zsh

I‘m aware of `date +%u` to get the day of the week for today.

I‘d like to get that integer for any arbitrary date i input - if possible in the format I choose (e.g. %YYmmdd)

Comment: The switches `date` accepts are not a shell thing. It's purely a `date` thing. Which implementation of `date` do you use (i.e. what operating system do you use)?

Comment: I modified my question, thx for pointing that out

Comment: @jens is it possible to write a script, with contains the date (or any other similar) command but still works on most platforms or do we have to differentiate within the script?

Comment: @matt : If you are going to write a script to achieve the goal, (1) don't write  _without script_ in the title of your question, and (2) show the script you have written so far and where you get stuck.

Comment: @user1934428 - I really wasn't writing a script. it was just a follow up question to jens' response :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, found it finally:

**`date -j -f %Y%m%d +%u 20200910`**

this is, because date on macOS doesn't take a switch for putting in custom date (fyi for those folks, how try to make `-v` work, like me^^)

in addition, -f affects only input format (it's literally the second word in the man page, but I managed to overlook more than once)

`-j` is needed to use `-f` without setting the date.

hope this will spare someone time in the future ;)

**edit:**
it seems to be important, to specify input format before output format (see comment from @chepner below)

*(also be careful with quotes)*

Comment: Regarding the order of the input and output formats, the input format is specified via the `-f` option, while the output format is an ordinary positional argument (albeit one that begins with a `+`), and the BSD library used to parse command-line arguments requires options to precede other arguments. This is in contrast to the corresponding GNU library, which scans the entire line for options.

Comment: thx for that :D really good to know. do you, by any chance, have an idea, what the upside on this behaviour is, which makes apple keeping it?

Comment: Apple's only involvement is that they are using the BSD tool chain, since the operating system itself is based on BSD. You might as well ask, though, why GNU *allows* mixing of options and arguments. Neither is really better or worse than the other; they are both simply long-standing conventions.

Comment: That said, Apple seems reluctant (to say the least) to distribute GNU or other GPL-licensed software, based on their refusal to upgrade `bash` and their recent move to replace `bash` with `zsh` (which is released under a fairly [simple license](https://sourceforge.net/p/zsh/code/ci/master/tree/LICENCE)) as the default user shell.

Comment: Coming from BSD explains it pretty much for me (thought since the mixed kernel of macOS (specifically the influence of OSF MK) it was a deliberated decision). Regarding ‚neither is worse‘-well, in one case you have to watch the order without having any benefits. Makes the other option preferably to me (ignoring the background of cause and assuming to use of full heritage tool set you have to port or map sth. anyway (**which isn’t obviously not happening!**)). Thx again for clarifying -this statement is mainly intended to help folks who are also get confused with the mentioned above as I did :)

Comment: @matt : Note that you can install the [GNU utilities](https://ryanparman.com/posts/2019/using-gnu-command-line-tools-in-macos-instead-of-freebsd-tools/) along with the ones from MacOS, so that you have both at your disposal.

Comment: Thanks you helped me a lot. I was able to add months with `-v +1m` to the input date with your command: `date -j -v +1m -f %Y-%m-%d +'%Y-%m-%d' 2021-01-01`

Answer (score -1):

```
$ date +%u -d "2020-09-10"
4
```

Comment: thx, but `-d` didn't work on macOS, that was my problem in the first place